# Codeigniter generating extra page link in pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

I have a paginated list of users where there are total 2 records with a pagination of 2. This means I should get only 1 link in pagination. But I am getting 2 links where 2nd link (i.e 2) should not be rendered.

Below is my Controller and Model code:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('users_model');
        $this->load->model('roles_model');
        $this->load->model('branches_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['page_title'] = 'Users';
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "admin/users";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->users_model->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 2;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment($config["uri_segment"])) ? $this->uri->segment($config["uri_segment"]) : 0;

        $this->data['users'] = $this->users_model->get_users(NULL,$config["per_page"], $page);
        $this->data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->render('admin/list_users_view');
    }
}
class Users_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function record_count() {
        return $this->db->count_all("users");
    }

    public function get_users($UserId = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $start = FALSE) {

        $this->db->select('users.*,roles.RoleName,branches.BranchName');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('roles', 'users.RoleId = roles.RoleId', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('branches', 'users.BranchId = branches.BranchId', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('users.BranchId',2);


        $filtered_count = $this->db->count_all_results('', false);
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();

        $data_array = array('total_records' => $filtered_count, 'records' => $query );
        return $data_array;
    }
}
```

[pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZFgY.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "This means I should get only 1 link in pagination. "?  1 link as "<-previus  2  next->" or one row in list?

Comment: I should only get <1> as my pagination string or it should be blank, because there are only 2 records and I have set $config['per_page'] = 2. Currently I am getting <1, 2 > where when I click on 2 it shows blank as there is not third record

Comment: can you add a print_r($data_array);  in Users_model  before return $data_array;  and count rows

Comment: i am getting correct count in print_r(). However, the issue is with $config["total_rows"] = $this->users_model->record_count(); method. Because it fetches all the 3 rows from table as there is not where condition $this->db->where('users.BranchId',2); as it is in .get_users() method of model

Answer (score 0):

Try to reordering the variables on the controllers and use the returned `total_records` from the model :

```
public function index()
{
    $this->data['page_title'] = 'Users';
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "admin/users";
    $config["per_page"] = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $page = ($this->uri->segment($config["uri_segment"])) ? $this->uri->segment($config["uri_segment"]) : 0;

    $this->data['users'] = $this->users_model->get_users(NULL,$config["per_page"], $page);

    $config["total_rows"] = $this->data['users']['total_records'];

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->render('admin/list_users_view');
}
```